# Massless limit of the Dirac theory

Tags: mass, field-theory, dirac-equation, spinors, chirality

What is the physical reason why there is no mixing between left-handed and right-handed Weyl spinors in the massless case of the Dirac theory?
Why does the chirality of a massive particle change depending on the reference frame you are in and thus it’s always a mixing of the left-handed and right handed component?

Comment: It's hard to know what you are looking for here. It's like asking for a physical reason why a massless entity propagates at $c$.

Comment: You might like the statement that there is an extra $U(1)$ symmetry in the limit $m \rightarrow 0$ which acts 'axially' on the left- and right-handed Weyl fermions.  At this level this is no more than observing that the mass term $m \psi_L \psi_R$ is the only coupling in the Lagrangian connecting $\psi_L$ and $\psi_R$, so when that term vanishes of course there is no mixing between them.

Comment: Your question should be reversed. It is the existence of the Dirac mass term that cause chirality to mix. The kinetic term for 1/2 spinors can always be separated into two chirality. Thus not mixing. It is impossible to construct a Lorentz invariant mass term with only one Weyl spinor. (I haven't checked so maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Bababeluma, your final statement is not correct. A neutral Weyl fermion can have a Majorana mass term all by itself.

Comment: @SethK Thanks for pointing out. I have trouble understanding the degrees of freedom of Majonara fermion. For example, I add a Majonara mass term for the right-handed Weyl spinor, it is neutral & right-handed, so it should only have one degree of freedom, yet right-handed Weyl spinor has two components. Can you explain what is wrong here.

Comment: The chirality of a particle is a Lorentz invariant, so it does not depend on the frame you are in.

Comment: @Bababeluma a Weyl fermion has two degrees of freedom, not one. Think of the spin-up vs. spin-down states of a Majorana neutrino, if you like.

Comment: @SethK If I'm not wrong, I think a massless Weyl spinor contains antiparticle since it has two degrees of freedom. But it looks like it should reduce to one when Majorana mass term is added, since Majorana fermion is said to be neutral (no antiparticles) and only right/left-handed (it involves only one Weyl spinor). Please tell me what is wrong in my statement.

Answer (score 10):

The [Dirac equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation)
$$(i\hbar\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-mc)\psi=0$$
in the massless case ($m=0$) becomes just
$$\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi=0. \tag{1}$$

For convenience let us use the [Weyl (or chiral) representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Weyl_(chiral)_basis):
$$
\gamma^0=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\quad
\gamma^{1,2,3}=\begin{pmatrix}0&\vec{\sigma}\\-\vec{\sigma}&0\end{pmatrix},\quad
\psi=\begin{pmatrix}\psi_L\\\psi_R\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then (1) becomes
$$\left(
\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\partial_0+
\begin{pmatrix}0&\vec{\sigma}\\-\vec{\sigma}&0\end{pmatrix}\vec{\nabla}
\right)
\begin{pmatrix}\psi_L\\\psi_R\end{pmatrix}=0 \tag{2}$$

Doing the matrix multiplication this becomes
$$\begin{align}
(\partial_0+\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{\nabla})\psi_R=0 \\
(\partial_0-\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{\nabla})\psi_L=0
\end{align} \tag{3}$$

Now we see, the left-handed spinor $\psi_L$ and the right-handed spinor $\psi_R$
evolve completely independent from each other, without any mixing.